# Is there some limit to the SQL statements that pyodbc can execute, and I get an error when executing a long SQL statement?

Tags: python, linux, pyodbc, freetds, unixodbc

I installed *FreeTDS* and *unixODBC* on CentOS 7, configured it and executed SQL query statements with pyodbc on Python 3.6 in order to fetch data from a remote *Sybase* database (SAP IQ 16) and found that executing simple statements was fine, but executing complex SQL statements would report an error, it would prompt. "***[HY000] [FreeTDS][SQL Server] Unknown error (0) (SQLExecDirectW)***".

The complex SQL statement is a combination of several simple SELECT statements with LEFT JOIN, about 10k words. The complex SQL statement can be executed correctly on the actual client, and if the complex SQL statement is split into several simple SELECT statements, they can be executed without any problems using pyodbc.

odbcinst.ini:

```
[FreeTDS]
Description     = Sybase
Setup           = /usr/lib64/libtdsS.so
Driver          = /usr/local/freetds/lib/libtdsodbc.so
FileUsage       = 1
UsageCount      = 1
```

odbc.ini:

```
[ENM2]
Driver = FreeTDS
Description = Sybase
Server = xx.xx.xx.xx
Port = 2642
Database = dwh_reader_2
TDS_Version = 5.0
Client_Charset = UTF-8
FileUsage = 1
```

Comment: It might help if you can include the query, even though it is long, so people can try to reproduce the error. Even if you replace any confidential information.

Answer (score 0):

I just found out that it is caused by the Decimal precision problem in the SQL statement. If the Decimal type with too high precision, an error will be reported. It is guessed that freeTDS has a limit on the maximum precision of the data